# Bash script not working on a new dedicated server

Tags: bash, freebsd

Recently I have migrated to the new dedicated server which is running on **the same** operating system - FreeBSD 8.2. I got a root account access and all permissions have been set properly.

My problem is that, the bash script I was running on the old server doesn't works on the new machine, the only error appearing while running the script is:

```
# sh script.sh
script.sh: 3: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

Here is the code itself:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

PORTS=(7777:GAME 11000:AUTH 12000:DB)
MESSG=""
for i in ${PORTS[@]} ; do
    PORT=${i%%:*}
    DESC=${i##*:}
    CHECK=`sockstat -4 -l | grep :$PORT | awk '{print $3}' | head -1`
    if [ "$CHECK" -gt 1 ]; then
        echo $DESC[$PORT] "is up ..." $CHECK
    else
        MESSG=$MESSG"$DESC[$PORT] wylaczony...\n"
        if [ "$DESC" == "AUTH" ]; then
            MESSG=$MESSG"AUTH is down...\n"
        fi
        if [ "$DESC" == "GAME" ]; then
            MESSG=$MESSG"GAME is down...\n"
        fi
        if [ "$DESC" == "DB" ]; then
            MESSG=$MESSG"DB is down...\n"
        fi

    fi
done

if [ -n "$MESSG" ]; then
    echo -e "Some problems ocurred:\n\n"$MESSG | mail -s "Problems" yet@another.com
fi
```

I don't really code in bash, so I don't know why this happend...

Answer (score 2):

Bourne shell (`sh`) doesn't support arrays, that's why you're running into this error when you use

```
sh script.sh
```

Use `bash` instead

```
bash script.sh
```

**Note**: I suspect that `sh script.sh` worked on the old server because `sh` is  linked to `bash` there.

Answer (score 1):

also you shouldn't need to run it through `sh` (that's what the 
`#!`
 on the first line is for - the OS will run the remainder of the line as a command and pass the contents of the file for it to interpret). Just make the script executable:
 `chmod +x script.sh`
and then you can just run it directly without the `sh` in front of the name.

It's possible that the default shell is not bash and so by running it through `sh` you're interpreting it with a different shell which is then giving the error

Comment: I did that as well - output: `# script.sh
script.sh: Command not found.` also tried running the script using this command : `./script.sh` but the output is the same as above.

Comment: Scott, the reason that you need to run it as ./script.sh is that the current directory is not in your PATH. The PATH environment variable tells the shell which directories to search for commands. You could (though it's a bad idea for security reasons) add "." to the PATH and then the shell will search whichever directory you are in for the command.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good.  It is likely that your new dedicated server is running older version of Bash than your last server.  Or maybe /usr/local/bin/bash is pointing towards older version.

Run

> $ which bash

if the output is other than `/usr/local/bin/bash` then change the first shebang line to the newer path, if it still does not work

Try replacing third line:

```
PORTS=(7777:GAME 11000:AUTH 12000:DB)
```

with

```
PORTS=('7777:GAME' '11000:AUTH' '12000:DB')
```

and rerun the script.

If it still does not work then post the BASH version here by running

```
$ bash --version
```

Comment: Output of the `which bash` is `/usr/local/bin/bash` and when I run the script via `/usr/local/bin/bash script.sh` then it is running...

Answer (score 0):

try with facing and trailing spaces

```
PORTS=( 7777:GAME 11000:AUTH 12000:DB )
```